# Segmentation Fault using Julia LibCurl Wrapper

Tags: curl, julia, libcurl

Running the Following Code with Julia `LibCurl.jl`

```
curl_header_list = Cstring[]

for header in keys(headers)
    value = headers[header]
    item =Cstring(pointer("$header: $value"))
    push!(curl_header_list, item)
end


curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "$burl/api/v1/order/bulk")
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, curl_header_list)

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

We are receiving the following segmentation fault error message:

```
signal (11): Segmentation fault
in expression starting at /home/ubuntu/speed_test.jl:208
Curl_safe_strcasecompare at /home/ubuntu/.julia/packages/LibCURL/lWJxD/deps/usr/lib/libcurl.so (unknown line)
Allocations: 3088296 (Pool: 3087464; Big: 832); GC: 6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using HTTP.jl?

```
using HTTP, JSON
headers = Dict("Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
url_2request = "https://your.url/abc"
#url_2request *= "?" * join(map(x -> x[1] * "=" * x[2], collect(params_dic)), "&")  # GET method
query_json  = JSON.json(Dict("query_id" => "1",
                             "version" => "1.0"))
r = HTTP.request("POST", url_2request, headers, query_json)
rs = String(r.body)
```